# StreamWriter can't open file because of a process

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

I got the following code

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
{

    // Write the HTML into this string builder

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    base.Render(hWriter);

    string pageHTML = sb.ToString(); 

    // Write it back to the server
    writer.Write(pageHTML);
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.ViewState["SendEmail"])) 
    {
        string HTML = "";
        HTML = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN'>";
        HTML += "<html>";
        HTML += "<head>";
        HTML += "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type'";
        HTML += "content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>";
        HTML += "<title>Order Information</title>";
        HTML += "</head>";
        HTML += "<body>";
        HTML += "See attachment for information.";
        HTML += "</body>";
        HTML += "</html>";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@xxx.com", "to@xxx.com", "Subject", HTML);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        string path = @"d:\websites\plate.html";

        using (StreamWriter sw11 = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw11.WriteLine(pageHTML);
        }

        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("192.168.1.127");

        client.Send( mail );

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Your information has been sent.')</script>");

        this.ViewState["SendEmail"] = false;
    }

}
```

After a fresh clean/build of my solution, when I press the send button, this function is called and the html page is sent in attachment by mail without a problem. But if I try to press again the send button, I'm getting "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'd:\websites\plate.html' because it is being used by another process." The error occur when I'm trying to open the file. What's wrong?

Comment: I hope the hard coded path is just for brevity here.  In production you'll have problems when (not if) two or more users do this at the same time.

Comment: Yes this is a hard coded path as for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric has pointed out, you should have the `SmtpClient` in a `using` statement - ditto `MailMessage`.

However, you'd still end up writing to the file system for no obvious reason. I'd strongly advise you to use one of the `Attachment` constructors which *doesn't* require a file to start with. You can write to a `MemoryStream`, rewind it, and then provide *that* to the `Attachment` for example.

Aside from anything else, that would mean you wouldn't have a problem if multiple threads (or processes) tried running this code at the same time.

Comment: The using statement for MailMessage corrected my problem :) Thanks Jon

Comment: @Shadowizoo: It may have helped your *immediate* problem, but I still see no reason to introduce a dependency on the file system here.

Comment: The only reason I didn't used that is only because I didn't knew about the MemoryStream. I did a little search and end up with memorystream instead of depending on the file system. Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

SmtpClient implements IDisposable but you are not disposing the instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

It may be holding on to the file for that reason.

Generally speaking, it is wise to wrap anything that implements IDisposable in a `using` statement unless you have a specific reason not to (e.g. your are explicitly managing the object lifetime via the class that holds an IDisposable instance).

I also want to draw attention to @DanPichelman's comment that you are using a constant file name, but this code may execute on separate threads in parallel.  That would cause the output file to be locked for any user past the first user, until the code completes for the first user.

Comment: I added client.Dispose(); after the client.Send( mail ); and I got the same problem.

Comment: You should use a *using* statement (whether or not this is the actual problem), or implement try/catch/finally yourself.  If there is an exception in the middle of the code, your client.Dispose() line will not be reached.

Comment: I used a using statement with smtpclient combined with MailMessage and the problem is solved. Thanks Eric.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should close it:

```
using (StreamWriter sw11 = File.CreateText(path))
{
    sw11.WriteLine(pageHTML);
    sw11.Flush();
    sw11.Close();
}
```

Comment: The `using` statement will dispose of it already (which will flush it too).

Comment: Sorry, this is fault and careless of me. I'm so sorry :(